# Why can't I style ion-button inside div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have ion-button with class "record-btn" inside div with class "bottom-section". I wanna make that button round(complete circle). But I can't do it with css. Here's my code.

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="bottom-section">
    <ion-button color="danger" size="large" class="record-btn">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="mic"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**SCSS**

```
.bottom-section .record-btn {
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

I also tried by removing class .bottom-section from SCSS but nothing happened. Can anyone please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're attempting to style an element encapsulated in the shadow DOM. To change the border-radius, you'd have to use the [custom CSS property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties) `--border-radius` provided by Ionic.

To get a circular button you'd need to do this, and force the width and height to be the same.

```css
.bottom-section .record-btn {
    --border-radius: 50%;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

However, a better solution for what you're trying to accomplish may be to use a [Floating Action Button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab) component